# Django sorl-thumbnail cannot identify image file

Tags: python, django

I have a couple of events that I run with a for loop in django template, I want to prevent those without images from displaying however I get this error

```
IOError at /buy-sell/category/housing/page/19

cannot identify image file

...

{% if e.picture.url %}
  {% thumbnail e.picture "300x600" as thumb %}
     <img src="{{ thumb.url }}" alt="{{ e.title }}" />
  {% endthumbnail %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: could you try {% if e.picture %} instead of {% if e.picture.url %}

Comment: tried that and it didn't work @user1797792

Comment: this error only shows when the 'e' object has no image? Or everytime?
Could you please provide more source code

Comment: it shows up when the e object has no image

Comment: What is the implementation/what is 'e' and if you do 'e.picture' in shell do you get a 'None' return as you are expecting? I am thinking that however 'e.picture' is implemented expects a file to be there but I can't answer that for sure without seeing code.